# Google Compute Engine VM other users listed in home

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Is it normal to see other user account names in the home folder of a Google Compute Engine VM?  Or should I be worried about nefarious activity?

[ls command on home directory of VM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9AYh.png)

ls -l on home dir, first 2 lines:

```
drwxr-xr-x 3 ankurshukla  ankurshukla  4096 Jul 28 22:20 ankurshukla
drwxr-xr-x 3 cpomeroy     cpomeroy     4096 Jul 28 22:20 cpomeroy
```

The VM was created today, August 23.  ???

Comment: Check last to see when we're the logins done by these users. If the users logged in after the VM was handed over to you, then that might be a concern.

Comment: It doesn't look right

Comment: last command only includes my username and "reboot" all from today.  the last line, however, includes: reboot   system boot  3.16.0-4-amd64   Thu Jul 28 22:20 - 22:23  (00:03)  which is the date of the other users' home folders, long before the VM was created (today).

Comment: I suggest you reach out to google support and try not to put anything sensitive (including internal host name setup etc user setup etc) until they clarify what's going on. Having said that, is this VM running a google authorized image or is it from some community based images or third party images? I know Amazon has that option, not sure if Google has similar concept.

Comment: it was created using the "Click to Deploy" link on this google page: https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/deploy-mongodb

Answer (score 0):

Discarding the fact that a [VM has been compromised](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131993/what-audit-log-files-are-created-in-linux-to-track-a-users-activities), I can think of two possibilities for having additional users in the home directory of a VM:

1) [Cloud Launcher](https://cloud.google.com/launcher/) feature uses pre-defined images to spin new VMs. If by any chance the original image was being tested and not fully cleaned before getting in production, it could have contained other users in the home directory. I can confirm that as per today this is not the case. I just deployed a VM using Cloud Launcher and the directory is not there. Nevertheless that could have happened with the image used one year ago.

2) An [SSH key](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys) is defined in the metadata of the project for that user.  By default, GCE instances run in their OS an [Account daemon](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/compute-image-packages#daemons). That daemon will sync with the project metadata and create users in the VM. As explained in [the article](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys#block-project-keys), the feature can be blocked. [If GKE is used,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39774881/unknown-users-in-home-gke-in-google-computer-engine/40008163#40008163) you might have in the home directory of the VMs users defined as “gke-xxxxxx”.